# How to protect REST Webservice where the website has no registration OR Authentication

Tags: web-services, rest

I am using Jersey REST Webservices for my Application which is like a type of blog website ( means no user registration or authentication are required)

I have some webservices which queries the database and sends the data to the Front End .

As you know the user can see the webservice calls in browser network tab and fire the query manually

My question is , how can i protect sever / Service from being hit continously (for loop written manually to break the application)

This is how my service looks like

```
@GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String displaylatestnews() {
        String latestnews = "";
        PreparedStatement selectpstmt = null;
        ResultSet selectRset = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        String selectsql = "SELECT  rssjson from rssfeeds limit 1";

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            selectpstmt = conn.prepareStatement(selectsql);
            selectRset = selectpstmt.executeQuery();

            if (selectRset.next()) {
                latestnews = selectRset.getString("rssjson");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                selectRset.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                selectpstmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "jsonCallback(" + latestnews.toString() + ")";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start avoiding creating a connection to mysql every time there's a request, secondly you can add some sort of caching to start with. Even a cache that only lasts few seconds can save tons of db accesses.